# JSON strange format

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I'm trying to reverse engineer some cake php code from years ago. The data is being stored in a format that looks like JSON, but I'm having trouble determining if this is custom format or a particular method for JSON.

The data is stored in a single field in this manner (I replaced some identifying data with letter t or number 1):

```
   a:7:{s:4:"site";a:11:s:13:"ttttttNumber";s:2:"13";s:14:"tttttttNumber";s:9:"001111111";s:11:"ttttSiteRef";s:16:"tt00170326300013";s:10:"tttttttttt";s:15:"D00170326300013";s:11:"ttttttName";s:28:"tttttt t tttt tt t t t ";s:19:"ttttttAddressLine1";s:17:"ttt t t t t tt t t ";s:19:"tttttAddressLine2";s:0:"";s:19:"ttttAddressLine3";s:6:"tttttt";s:19:"tttttAddressLine4";s:2:"CA";s:15:"ttttttPostcode";s:10:"11111-9424";s:7:"Address";s:29:"tttttt tttt,tt tttt";}s:15:"tttt_reference";i:8296;s:6:"detail";a:11:{s:10:"ttttt_type";s:3:"SVM";s:12:"end_datetime";s:19:"09/06/2014 10:40 PM";s:8:"site_ref";s:15:"001703263/00013";s:4:"note";s:29:"tttttttttttt t t t tt t t ";s:12:"contact_name";s:0:"";s:13:"tttttt_visit";s:2:"-1";s:10:"ttttttttt";s:12:"486900096869";...
```

I can tell the s:# is the number of characters in the string and i: seems to mean integer. I'd like to find if there is a simple way to decode this into an array, similar to json_decode.

Comment: Look into serialize/unserialize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: It may look like JSON, but it is not. It's an object (an array, actually) serialized as a string.

Comment: `a`rray length = `7` first element {`s`tring length = `4` value = `site`; etc...

Comment: I thought the very first comment will be enough to consider the case closed. ) @FishBulbX - just use `unserialize` on that string to get the data back.

Comment: @raina77ow: Me too...

Comment: Yes... unserialize is exactly the answer I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode($jsonString,true); this will convert that data into array

Comment: This is a PHP serialized string, not JSON. Btw, there's no `jason_decode` (you mean `json_decode`). Please think before you post.